# Static initialization with pointer to extern variable

Tags: c, portability, linkage, python-internals

I would like to understand the innards of the Python import system, including the rough spots. In the Python C API [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/newtypes.html), there's this terse reference to one such rough spot:

> This is so important that we’re going to pick the top of it apart
>   still further:
>
> ```
> PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
> ```
>
> This line is a bit of a wart; what we’d like
>   to write is:
>
> ```
> PyObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type)
> ```
>
> as the type of a type object is
>   “type”, but this isn’t strictly conforming C and some compilers
>   complain.

Why is this not strictly conforming C? Why do some compilers accept this without complaint and others do not?

*I now think the following is misleading, skip down to "SUBSTANTIAL EDIT"*

Scrolling about a page down there is what I believe is a clue. This quote regards initializing another member of the struct but it sounds like the same issue and this time it is explained.

> We’d like to just assign this to the tp_new slot, but we can’t, for
>   portability sake, On some platforms or compilers, we can’t statically
>   initialize a structure member with a function defined in another C
>   module

This still leaves me a bit confused, in part due to the odd word choice of "module". I think the second quote meant to say that static initialization that relies on calls to functions in separate compilation units is a non-standard extension. I still don't understand why that would be so. Is that what's going on in the first quote?

**SUBSTANTIAL EDIT:**

The use of `PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)` is advised to go at the very top of the initialization of an instance of `PyTypeObject`.

The definition of PyTypeObject looks like this:

```
typedef struct _typeobject {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    const char *tp_name; /* For printing, in format "<module>.<name>" */
    Py_ssize_t tp_basicsize, tp_itemsize; /* For allocation */

    /* Methods to implement standard operations */

    destructor tp_dealloc;

/*... lots more ... */

} PyTypeObject;
```

The `PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)` macro is used to initialize the top of PyTypeObject instances. The top of the `PyTypeObject` definition is created by the macro `PyObject_VAR_HEAD`. `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` is:

```
/* PyObject_VAR_HEAD defines the initial segment of all variable-size
 * container objects.  These end with a declaration of an array with 1
 * element, but enough space is malloc'ed so that the array actually
 * has room for ob_size elements.  Note that ob_size is an element count,
 * not necessarily a byte count.
 */
#define PyObject_VAR_HEAD               \
    PyObject_HEAD                       \
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
#define Py_INVALID_SIZE (Py_ssize_t)-1
```

In turn, `PyObject_HEAD` expands to:

```
/* PyObject_HEAD defines the initial segment of every PyObject. */
#define PyObject_HEAD                   \
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA                \
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;               \
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
```

`_PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA` is only used in debugging builds and normally expands to nothing. The members being initialized by the PyObject_HEAD_INIT macro are ob_refcnt and ob_type. ob_type is the one that we would like to initialize with `&PyType_Type` but we're told that would violate the C Standard. ob_type points to a _typeobject, which is typedef'd as a PyTypeObject (the same struct that we're trying to initialize). We use the PyObject_HEAD_INIT macro, which initializes those two values, expands as so:

```
#define PyObject_HEAD_INIT(type)        \
    _PyObject_EXTRA_INIT                \
    1, type,
```

So we're starting a reference count at 1 and setting a member pointer to whatever is in the type parameter. The Python documentation says we can't set the type parameter it to the address of PyType_Type because that is not strictly standard C so we settle for NULL.

`PyType_Type` is declared in the same translation unit a few lines below.

```
PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyType_Type; /* built-in 'type' */
```

`PyAPI_DATA` is defined elsewhere. It has a few different conditional definitions.

```
#define PyAPI_DATA(RTYPE) extern __declspec(dllexport) RTYPE
#define PyAPI_DATA(RTYPE) extern RTYPE
```

So the Python API documentation is saying that we'd like to initialize an instance of a PyTypeObject with a pointer to previously declared PyTypeObject that was declared with the extern qualifier. What in the C Standard would that violate?

The initialization of PyType_Type occurs in a .c file. A typical Python extension that initializes a PyTypeObject, as described above, will be dynamically loaded by code that was compiled with this initialization:

```
PyTypeObject PyType_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "type",                                     /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PyHeapTypeObject),                   /* tp_basicsize */
    sizeof(PyMemberDef),                        /* tp_itemsize */
    (destructor)type_dealloc,                   /* tp_dealloc */

/* ... lots more ... */
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of PyObject_VAR_HEAD, which PyObject_HEAD_INIT(...) is the initializer for?

Comment: I think this is veering off course but the definition is #define PyObject_VAR_HEAD \ PyObject_HEAD \ Py_ssize_t ob_size; I can tunnel through the macros and add a to that it in a few minutes.

Comment: "I think this is veering off course" -- Well then, you're lacking basic understanding. What you need to know here is the type of the thing that `&PyType_Type` (or NULL) is initializing. So next you should post the definition of PyObject_HEAD. And if that is defined in terms of yet another macro, post its definition, and so on. Unless you don't actually want any help.

Comment: "I think the second quote meant to say that static initialization that relies on calls to functions in separate compilation units is a non-standard extension." -- No, not a *call* of a function, the *address* of a function. But there's nothing non-standard about that. However, the standard isn't what matters when writing highly portable code ... you have to account for *non* standard compilers ... although I don't know what compiler has such a limitation.

Comment: I've tried to improve the question and provide all the needed definitions. Would anything else help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PyObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type)
```

Produces

```
1, &PyType_Type
```

which initializes fields

```
Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
struct _typeobject *ob_type;
```

PyType_Type is defined with `PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyType_Type` which produces

```
extern PyTypeObject PyType_Type;
```

possibly with a __declspec qualifier. PyTypeObject is a typedef for struct _typeobject, so we have

```
extern struct _typeobject PyType_Type;
```

so `PyObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type)` would initialize the `struct _typeobject* ob_type` field with a `struct _typeobject*` ... which is certainly valid C, so I don't see why they say it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon an explanation of this elsewhere in the Python source code.

```
/* We link this module statically for convenience.  If compiled as a shared
   library instead, some compilers don't allow addresses of Python objects
   defined in other libraries to be used in static initializers here.  The
   DEFERRED_ADDRESS macro is used to tag the slots where such addresses
   appear; the module init function must fill in the tagged slots at runtime.
   The argument is for documentation -- the macro ignores it.
*/
#define DEFERRED_ADDRESS(ADDR) 0
```

And then the macro is used where `NULL` appears at the top of the OP.

```
PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(DEFERRED_ADDRESS(&PyType_Type), 0)
```